# Include an ALL inclusive category using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

If I have a CASE expression which reads:

```
CASE WHEN Category='A' THEN 'Discharged'
     WHEN Category='B' THEN 'Not Discharged'
     WHEN Category='A' OR Category='B' THEN 'Both'
   END AS Status
```

I notice that the CASE does not show a separate 'Both' Status record. It only shows 'Discharged' or 'Not Discharged'. Is there a way to make the CASE expression include a separate 'Both' result alongwith each 'Discharged' or 'Not Discharged' Result?

If I code the condition for 'Both' above 'Discharged' or 'Not Discharged', the output shows 'Both' for all records. Which I believe goes with the logic that CASE is sequential.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Also can you post the whole query?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this, does category can only fall into A and B? if that is the case, why dont just print 'both' for every record apart the discharged/not discharged?

Comment: This Status field actually gets fed into a BI tool to be used as a filter. The 'Both' status would let me display all results, instead of having to choose an either/or between Discharged and Not Discharged.

Comment: Are there Category values other than A & B?

Comment: Did you mean, if there are 2 records of the same id with different category 'A' and 'B' each ('Discharged' and 'Not Discharged', there should be another row that will have 'Both' value for the status?

Comment: @AS91, you should code that in the filter of the BI tool instead

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar If Person1 was Discharged, he should have Status as both Discharged and 'Both'. If Person2 was not discharged, his status should be 'Not discharged' and 'Both'. It's not that the same person was both discharged and not discharged, it's that they should be included in an overall "Both" or "All" selection such that I can see ALL the results when I select that. Sadly, Yellowfin doesn't give an option like Tableau does for "All" and I can only manipulate the data in SQL

Comment: @JasonA.Long No.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` expressions are evaluated in order of "appearance" in code and are short circuited. In your case move the last `WHEN` to the first position.

`CASE` expressions use Boolean comparisons and not bitwise.

```
CASE
    WHEN Category='A' AND Category='B' THEN 'Both'
    WHEN Category='A' THEN 'Discharged'
    WHEN Category='B' THEN 'Not Discharged'
END AS Status
```

For bitwise comparisons try this:

```
DECLARE @Category INT = ASCII('A' )|ASCII('B')
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Category = (ASCII('A' )|ASCII('B')) THEN 'Both'
        WHEN @Category= ASCII('A') THEN 'Discharged'
        WHEN @Category= ASCII('B') THEN 'Not Discharged'
    END AS Status
```

**Note:** it is a good idea to have an `ELSE` condition as well to avoid `NULL` being returned if non of your conditions match.

See for full list of bitwise operators and usages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql

If you want to filter by that expression i.e. it appears in the `WHERE` clause then you need to write it differently:

```
DECLARE @SearchCriteria VARCHAR( 50 )
SET @SearchCriteria = 'Both'
SELECT Category
FROM ( VALUES( 'A' ), ( 'B' )) AS a( Category )
WHERE
    Category = ( CASE @SearchCriteria
        WHEN 'Discharged' THEN 'A'
        WHEN 'Not Discharged' THEN 'B'
        WHEN 'Both' THEN Category
    END )
```

Comment: AND wouldn't work because the Category on a row level can't be both A and B. The idea of Both is that it's all inclusive. Not that it can be both Discharged and Not Discharged at the same time. It's a redundant row showing status as 'Both' so that when I filter on Both, I basically get every status possible. 2 in this case. +1 on including ELSE but I didn't here to keep things little more simpler.

Comment: @AS91 - hopefully the 3rd alternative is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION

```
SELECT person_id,
       ...
       CASE WHEN Category='A' THEN 'Discharged'
            WHEN Category='B' THEN 'Not Discharged'
        END AS Status
  FROM table
 UNION
SELECT person_id,
       ...
       'Both' AS Status
  FROM table
```